# How to find the number of times particular file has been modified in given time range

Tags: linux, bash, file, shell, unix

How to find the number of times particular file has been modified in given time range i.e in last 2 days in Unix client?

Answer (score 1):

As seen in [UNIX & Linux Stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/24442)

> Linux offers three timestamps for files: **time of last access of
>   contents** (atime), **time of last modification of contents** (mtime),
>   and **time of last modification of the inode** (metadata, ctime). So,
>   no, you cannot. The directory's mtime corresponds to the last file
>   creation or deletion that happened, though.

So you cannot know neither the creation time, neither the history of the modifications.

Answer (score 1):

The linux kernel uses [inode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) for files in filesystems these inodes do not log changes in the filesystem, you can however ask for the last change through mtime example `find testfile -mtime 2` this will tell you if the file has changed in the last 48 hours.

You are looking the log changes to the file, you could use inotify for that. Or the [inotifywait](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) tool. Which let's you efficiently wait for changes in a file.

I suggest inotifywait.